# How do I list all currently installed "winetricks"?

Tags: winetricks

Is there a way to list all the "tricks" you've installed using `winetricks`?

<sub>(I'd like to submit a report to the [AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/) and I don't know which exact packages I've installed over the months.)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/winetricks.1.html) this should do the trick:

```
 winetricks list-installed
```

Also have a look at the settings via

```
 winetricks settings list
```